# Connecting to Oracle12c database - .NET

Tags: .net, nhibernate, oracle12c

Did anyone try to connect to Oracle12c database using .NET? I had installed oracle driver (documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48297_01/doc/win.121/e41125/InstallODP.htm). I had added references to Oracle.DataAccess.dll also. My program works on sql server. I changed this part app.config file:

```
  <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle12cDialect</property>
  <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
  <property name="connection.connection_string_name">db</property>
  <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleDataClientDriver</property>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

When i try to run program i get error with message:
Message = "Could not compile the mapping document: Orders.Model.Mappings.ShopOrder.hbm.xml"
and inner exception:
InnerException = {"Could not instantiate dialect class NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle12cDialect"}

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Oracle12cDialect` does not exist yet, so you really need to use `Oracle10gDialect`

Comment: Any update on when Oracle12cDialect will be available???
Is it safe to use in Production Oracle10gDialect to connect to 12c oracle?

Comment: Thanks for quick help, I am using FluentNHibernate to configure db and it does not have 12c, that is why i thought it is not supported by NHibernate